# Increase nice value for many processes

Tags: process, nice

Say I have launched a couple of non-timecritical applications such as a text editor a web browser etc and one more time critical (audio)application.

Is there a utility that simulates the opposite of nice by increasing nice value for all my other process or do I need to write a script for that.

Comment: What other processes? Do you want to increase the nice value for all but one process? Could you be more specific? You know you can use `renice` to increase or decrease the nice value of a running job right?

Answer (score 4):

Surely there must be a better way than this, but on most Linux-based systems:

```
ps -o pid -C pidgin --no-headers --deselect
```

will give you all pids on the system, apart from those for the command `pidgin`, so

```
renice -n 5 $(ps -o pid -C pidgin --no-headers --deselect)
```

will try to renice everything but`pidgin`, but fail for processes you don't own

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is not quite answering the question from a `nice` perspective, but would it be more helpful to completely stop the unused programs by suspending them? From what you describe the programs are interactive, rather than batch processes etc. and there is no need to have them consume any resource if they are unused.

You could use:

`kill -STOP <pid>`

and resume again with:

`kill -CONT <pid>`

If the program is running in a shell terminal `ctrl-Z` suspends the program, and `fg` (foreground) plus the job number, resumes.